# Deleting rows in parent table when there is no parent_id association in child tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've one parent table called Location with 20,000 rows and two child tables namely, Customer and Shop which have around 8000 rows. I want to get rid of Locations which do not have children in both the tables. Tables looks like below:

Parent Table 1: Location: ID_Location(PK), ID_City(FK)

```
| Zip  | ID_Location |
|------|-------------|
| 0001 | 1           |
| 0011 | 2           |
| 0002 | 3           |
| 0021 | 4           |
| 0003 | 5           |
| 0012 | 6           |
```

Child Table 1: Customer: Cust_ID(PK), ID_Location(FK)

```
| Cust_ID | ID_Location |
|---------|-------------|
| 1       | 1           |
| 2       | 3           |
| 3       | 5           |
| 4       | 2           |
| 5       | 1           |
```

Child Table 3: Shop: Shop_ID(PK), ID_Location(FK)

```
| Shop_ID | ID_Location |
|---------|-------------|
| 1       | 1           |
| 2       | 2           |
| 3       | 6           |
| 4       | 3           |
| 5       | 1           |
```

Required output: I want the row in Location table with ID_Location = 4 to get deleted since it does not have any child rows in either of the child tables.

What I have done is,

```
select * from Location where ID_Location not in (select ID_Location from Customer)

select * from Location where ID_Location not in (select ID_Location from Shop)
```

then I run delete query on the rows that come up,

```
delete from Location where ID_Location = 4
```

Is there a way to run nested query to get rows which do not have any entry in child table?

Comment: delete from Location where ID_Location not in (select ID_Location from Customer) AND ID_Location not in (select ID_Location from Shop) union might be more efficient, tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//One way of doing is getscalar cols from the child tables and exclude from 
  the parent

delete from Location 
where ID_Location  not in
(
Select ID_Location from Customer
union
Select ID_Location from Shop
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query

```
DELETE FROM LOC
FROM Location LOC
LEFT JOIN Customer CUST ON CUST.ID_Location = LOC.ID_Location
LEFT JOIN SHOP SH ON SH.ID_Location = LOC.ID_Location
WHERE CUST.ID IS NULL AND SH.ID IS NULL
```

If you want to ensure you're operating in the appropriate records run this first:

```
SELECT LOC.*, CUST.ID, SH.ID
FROM Location LOC
LEFT JOIN Customer CUST ON CUST.ID_Location = LOC.ID_Location
LEFT JOIN SHOP SH ON SH.ID_Location = LOC.ID_Location
WHERE CUST.ID IS NULL AND SH.ID IS NULL
```